# how to construct a sequence of positive integers with a unique sum of any contiguous numbers?

Tags: algorithm, numbers, sum, sequence

For example: 1,2,4,5 has the following sum:

1,2,4,5

3,6,9

7,11

12

and every sum is unique.

Now, 1,2,3 has the following sum:

1,2,3

3,5

6

and apparently not every sum is unique.

Is there any efficient way to generate similar sequence to the first example with the goal of picking every number as small as possible (not just 1,2,4,8,16...)? I understand I could write a program to perhaps bruteforce this, but I'm just curious can it be done in a better way.

Comment: if you bruteforce it, you might discover a better way. and you'll learn something in any case.

Comment: Do you want the sequence to be increasing?  If so, the search is pretty easy (O(n^2), I think).  If not, David Yaw is right about this being the Golomb Ruler problem in disguise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think what you're looking for here is a [Golomb Ruler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_ruler). If you take the numbers you're describing above as the distance between marks, you've described a Golomb Ruler. When the set of marks on a ruler has no duplicates, as you've described, that's what makes it a Golomb Ruler.

It appears the standard way to describe a Golomb Ruler is by representing the location of each mark, not the distances between them. Therefore, your 1,2,4,5 would be described as a Golomb Ruler 0-1-3-7-12.

Quoting Wikipedia:

> Currently, the complexity of finding OGRs of arbitrary order n (where
>   n is given in unary) is unknown. In the past there was some
>   speculation that it is an NP-hard problem. Problems related to the
>   construction of Golomb Rulers are provably shown to be NP-hard, where
>   it is also noted that no known NP-complete problem has similar flavor
>   to finding Golomb Rulers.

Comment: Wow, excellent background! Well, apart from the fact that the OP gives different values to the first line, I think this is the right answer. Thanks for sharing this with us!

Comment: This is certainly the best answer I've seen so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Seen <- emtpy set  # Sums seen so far
Open <- empty set  # Sums ending at the last element
for x from 1 to Limit do
    if x in Seen then
        # quick fail
        continue with next x
    end
    # Build new set
    Pending <- empty set
    add x to Pending
    for each s in Open do
        add (s+x) to Pending
    end
    # Check if these numbers are all unique
    if (Pending intersection Seen) is empty then
        # If so, we have a new result
        yield x
        Open <- Pending
        Seen <- Seen union Pending
    end
end
```

It looks at all sums seen so far, and the sums ending at the last element. There is no need to keep track of starting and ending positions.

If *n* is the value of `Limit`, this algorithm would take *O(n<sup>2</sup> log n)*, assuming set member check and insertion are *O(log n)*, and intersection/union are not slower than *O(n log n)*.

(Though I might be mistaken on the last assumption)

The first few values would be:

```
1, 2, 4, 5, 8
```

Comment: This assumes the sequence is increasing, which the questioner does not make clear.

Answer (score 0):

The first 30 values (when selecting always the smallest possible value for the next difference) are

`1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 14, 21, 15, 16, 26, 25, 34, 22, 48, 38, 71, 40, 74, 90, 28, 69, 113, 47, 94, 54, 46, 143, 153, 83`

These "lexicograpic first" Golomb rulers are less than twice as long as the best known Golomb rulers with up to 30 differences. For most purposes such rulers are sufficient - for signals it just matters that all distances between any two marks are different. Finding the OGR (the optimum Golomb ruler) is rather a mathematical challenge.

@David There is no right or wrong in using one or the other format for describing Golomb rulers. Either is valid, displaying the positions of the marks (0, 1, 3, 7, 12, 20, ...) or the values of the differences. Personally, I prefer the differences for calculations, like @zack does in the question.